# Shutdown\Startup Guest VM

Tags: powershell

Windows Server 2008 R2 host running A Hyper-V Windows 2000 Server guest VM.

I am looking for a simple way (either batch, VBS or PowerShell command) to shutdown the guest VM and then start it up at a time of my choosing.

I have installed the "PowerShell Management Library for Hyper-V" and used the following commands with success ONLY after right-clicking PowerShell and selecting "Run as Administrator":

Import-Module "C:\Program Files\modules\HyperV\HyperV.psd1"
shutdown-vm "VM_NAME" -force

However no matter what I do I can not get this run as a scheduled task. it does not error out but it just doesn't run.

I have tried several combinations using the "Start-Process powershell -verb runas" which if I manually type that command into PowerShell will bring up another PowerShell box run in admin context I assume but none of this I can get working with a scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

To begin, the command is `Stop-VM` rather than `Shutdown-VM`, but I suspect you'll have some further issues so let me break it down.

You can skip a step in the PowerShell script you're trying to run. Navigate to the path `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\`. There should be a `Modules` directory, if there isn't use your admin credentials to add one. If one does exist, open it to see if the Hyper-V module directory is in there or not. If it isn't, again with admin credentials copy it in there. The structure should be like this

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\
|-- Modules
  |-- Hyper-V
    |-- Hyper-V.Format.ps1xml
    |-- Hyper-V.Types.ps1xml
    |-- Hyper-V.psd1
```

This will automatically load this module on all accounts when you start up PowerShell.

Next, ensure you have your execution policy set correctly. Your script may be stopping because the [Execution Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347641.aspx) is set to a high security level. This is dependent upon your level of security on whatever system you are working. Follow whatever guidelines you need to, but you can open up a PowerShell session as Administrator with your admin credentials and type the following:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
```

This will permanently change the execution policy for that admin user regardless if the current PS session gets closed.

Finally, open up Task Scheduler as Admin and create a new task. Change the user who will be running the task to the same user you used for setting the execution policy.

You can either create a script file and use that when you run the program for the task scheduler or you can use the PowerShell.exe `-Command` argument with a script block

```
# So either your desired commands in a file
# .\script.ps1
Stop-VM <VM Name>

#This is what the command in task scheduler would look like
powershell.exe -File "absolute\path\to\script.ps1"

# Or use a command directly
powershell.exe -Command "& {Stop-VM <VM-Name>}"
```

This *should* be all you need to do. If not let me know and I can revise.